# NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python-3.8, calculo

la verdad soy nuevo en esto de programar y estoy tratando de hacer un calculadora de la segunda ley de newton mi problema es que a la hora se escoger una opción diferente (F ó M) a la primera (M) me sale error

```
print("Calculadora de la segunda ley de newton")
m=float(input("Introduce tu masa:" ))
print(f"{m} kg")
f=float(input("Introduce tu fuerza:" ))
print(f"{f} N")
a=float(input("Introduce tu aceleracion:"))
print(f"{a} m/s^2")
opcion=input("Selecciona lo que quieras \n\
M=Masa \n\
F=Fuerza \n\
A=Aceleracion \n\
")
if opcion=="M":
    Res=(f/a)
print(f"Tu masa es de: {Res}" + " kg")
quit()
if opcion=="F":
    yaya=(m*a)
print(f"Tu fuerza es de: {yaya}" + " N")
quit()
if opcion=="A":
    ptm=(f/m)
print(f"Tu aceleracion es de: {ptm}" + " m/s^2")
quit()
```

Muchas gracias, si tienen recomendaciones para mi código o para programar son mas que bienvenidas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongo que el mensaje correcto que te sale es

```
NameError: name 'quit' is not defined
```

Por lo tanto el comando quit no está definido, quita ese comando y prueba otra vez.

```
print("Calculadora de la segunda ley de newton")
m = float(input("Introduce tu masa:" ))
print(f"{m} kg")

f = float(input("Introduce tu fuerza:" ))
print(f"{f} N")

a = float(input("Introduce tu aceleracion:"))
print(f"{a} m/s^2")

opcion=input("Selecciona lo que quieras \n\
M=Masa \n\
F=Fuerza \n\
A=Aceleracion \n\
")

if opcion == 'M':
    res = f/a
    print(f"Tu masa es de: {res}" + " kg")
elif opcion == 'F':
    yaya = m*a
    print(f"Tu fuerza es de: {yaya}" + " N")
else:
    ptm = f/m
    print(f"Tu aceleracion es de: {ptm}" + " m/s^2")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me sale la respuesta :).

Comment: @SamuelGonzalez El problema no era que `quit()` no estuviera definido. Esa función es parte de python y por tanto sí está definida. El problema era la indentación de los `print()` que no estaban dentro de los correspondientes `if`, por lo que el primer `print()`, al intentar mostar `res` encontraba que esa variable no estaba definida (porque se defína sólo si se había ejecutado el correspondiente `if`. Del mismo modo los `quit()` también deberían estar dentro de los `if` porque de otro modo se ejecutarían siempre tras el primer `print()` y el programa terminaría.